# How to call the following cs function by html button in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // C# code for SQL connection
} 

<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Pakistan"  onclick ="Button1_Click()" />
```

Comment: you can use the asp .net button control.

Comment: why cant you just use the regular button with which you created the Button1_Click Event? I believe you are complicating yourself too much. The asp control will create an HTML button that will fire this onclick event, that is it! you dont need to do anything else. Unless what you want is a separate button to fire the same event then that is something else but not as complex really

Answer (score 0):

OK there is one solution if you insist on using the Input type Button instead of using the normal Asp:Button

```
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Pakistan" onclick ="button2();"/>

<script>
function button2()
{
   __doPostBack('Button2', 'postback')
}

</script>
```

now in your page load  in C# code behind file:

protected void Page_Load(Object sender,EventArgs e)
    {

```
if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"]=="Button2")
{
//call the Code for Sql Connection

}


}
```

regards

Comment: But it donot load my data from sql server my list box remains empty when i press the button

Comment: if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"]=="Button2")
{
//call the Code for Sql Connection

}
The condition is not executing.When I Press the html button

Comment: Kindly give me more explanation